# How do I split into train and test set after creating dummy variables?

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, regression, training-data

I have already created dummy variables for all my categorical columns, but I need to split my data into train and test set, with my target being "Loan_Status". I am confused because after creating dummy variables, this creates two new columns for "Loan_Status", so when or how would I split my data and create the target?

```
# Convert the categorical features into dummy variables.

df_dummies = pd.get_dummies(df1, columns=['Gender', 'Married', 'Dependents', 'Education', 'Self_Employed', 'Loan_Status'])
df_dummies.head()
```

turns into this [image: loan status after creating dummy variables, now two columns]

It looked like this before, so how would i create the target to be loan status, wouldnt splitting the data before dummys create issues? [image]

Answer (score 0):

As a rule of thumb, you should stick to `pd.get_dummies(drop_first=True, ...)` to avoid creating redundant columns, as N-1 columns contain full information about N possible values.

However, one hot encoding is a bit excessive for binary values, you're probably better off just using something like `.map()`.

Comment: so something like this?
```
x = pd.get_dummies(df1.drop('Loan_Status', axis = 1), drop_first = True)
y = df1['Loan_Status']
x.head()
```
 I ended up getting value errors when trying to fit my mode, is this due to the Loan_status being categorical?

Comment: Likely. I'd just use something like y = df['Loan_Status'].map(dict(Y=1, N=0))